# How to tweak 3-5 authors citation with the biblatex-apa style?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, author-number

One thing about the `biblatex-apa` style I could not get used to, is the 3-5 authors citation: if the authors number is between 3-5, all of them will be printed in citation.

e.g. Biblatex-apa style:

> - [Citation] Goossens, Mittelbach, Samarin and Peter (2020)
> - [Bibliography] Goossens, M., Mittelbach, F., Samarin, A.  & Peter, T. (2020). *How to DIY a nuclear bomb at home* (1st ed.). Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley.

Sometimes the authors list is really long in text, and I thought it is indeed not necessary. So how to make the `maxcitenames` number to `2`, just like the built in biblatex styles do.

MWE is provided:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    maxcitenames=2,  % no effect!      
    natbib=true] {biblatex} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\LetLtxMacro{\cite}{\citet} %

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

\section*{Apa citation}

Article - 2 authors: \cite{sarfraz}\\
Article - 3 authors: \cite{companion}\\
In proceeding: \cite{salam}\\
Ph.D thesis:  \cite[see e.g.][]{geer} \\
Master thesis: \cite{loh}\\
Report: \cite{padhye}\\
Repeat citation:  \cite{companion}, \citet{companion}, \citep{companion} \\
Multi-citation:  \cite{bertram,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c} \\
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes the `maxcitenames` apparently has no effect in `biblatex-apa`. I faced this issue where the `biblatex-apa` was very close to the style I required but I did not want all the author names for 3-5 authors and I also didn't want the implementation of *first cite* as described in the APA style.

The solution is to alter the code that causes this, you can find it in the file `apa.cbx` and it is usually in `...../tex/latex/biblatex-apa`.

The corresponding piece of code is the following:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{uniquelist}>1}
    {\numdef\cbx@min{\value{uniquelist}}}
    {\numdef\cbx@min{\value{minnames}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{1}}
              or test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{=}{2}}}
    {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{>}{5}}
                 or test {\ifciteseen}}
     {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{<}{\cbx@min + 1}% normal name
       {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}%
       {}%
      \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{\cbx@min + 1}% first past ul is et al
      % but enforce plurality of et al - only truncate here if there is at
      % least one more element after the current potential truncation point
      % so that "et al" covers at least two elements.
       {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{<}{\value{listtotal}}
         {\andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
         {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}}%
       {}%
      \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{>}{\cbx@min + 1}% nothing thereafter
       {\relax}%
       {}}%
     {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}}}
```

One of the things this code does is check if the number of authors is > 5 or if the entry has already been cited, if so; then it assigns `et al` after the first author. By altering the code, changing the `5` to `2` and getting rid of `or test {\ifciteseen}` (watch out for the closing bracket), then any citation with more than 2 authors will have `et al` regardless if it has been used or not. Here's the edited part in addition to `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` which are required when putting this into the document preamble

```
\makeatletter

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{uniquelist}>1}
    {\numdef\cbx@min{\value{uniquelist}}}
    {\numdef\cbx@min{\value{minnames}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{1}}
              or test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{=}{2}}}
    {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{>}{\value{maxnames}}}}% <- EDIT
     {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{<}{\cbx@min + 1}% normal name
       {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}%
       {}%
      \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{\cbx@min + 1}% first past ul is et al
      % but enforce plurality of et al - only truncate here if there is at
      % least one more element after the current potential truncation point
      % so that "et al" covers at least two elements.
       {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{<}{\value{listtotal}}
         {\andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
         {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}}%
       {}%
      \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{>}{\cbx@min + 1}% nothing thereafter
       {\relax}%
       {}}%
     {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}}}

\makeatother
```

The `xpatch` package provides an easy way to apply the same change to the `labelname` formatting directive.

```
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,natbib=true,
            maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false]{biblatex} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchnameformat{labelname}
  {\ifciteseen}{\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{>}{\value{maxnames}}}{}{}
```

Comment: @Audrey, using the setting before or after `biblatex`? because using it before the `biblatex` setting gets no error nor effect. After ... gets a lot errors

Comment: @Audrey, thanks a lot, I'm still a beginner when it comes to such stuff :D. Anyway, I get an `undefined control sequence`, I read the `xpatch` documentation and your syntax seems to be correct, don't know why.

Comment: @Audrey I added your answer although it's still giving me an undefined control sequence!

Comment: @AbdulhaqElhouderi I made an edit. Using that code, I don't get any errors on my end. If your errors persist, which control sequence is undefined?

Comment: @Audrey `! Undefined control sequence.l.14 \xpatchnameformat{labelname}`

I also can't see anything wrong with the loading if `xpatch`, here's the corresponding line in the log for the command giving the error:
`. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \xpatchbibdriver with arg. spec. 'm' on line 133.`

Comment: @AbdulhaqElhouderi Which `xpatch` version do you have? `xpatchnameformat` was introduced to 0.3, release 2012/10/02.

Comment: That solves everything, the log says `0.2`: `Package: xpatch 2012/01/13 v0.2`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: another minor issue: how to get ride of the warning info when using `apa-style`: `Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'name:apa:last-first' undefined. (biblatex) Using \newbibmacro.`  and `Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'name:apa:first-last' undefined. (biblatex) Using \newbibmacro.`